# Image Panning Effect - Vertical - Mouse Over

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, panning

Looking for a code that can be utilized to create the same vertical 'image panning' / 'mouse over' effect as [in this example](http://demo.undsgn.com/egofolio/light/portfolio/double-trouble/) for the following [WordPress themes full screen images](http://pixelthemes.net/immersion/)

Your replies appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode for one approach.

```
css
.div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}

jQuery
$('#theimage').mousemove(function(event){
    $('#theimage').css('top', function(current){
        return current + event.pageY + offset; 
        //offset is what sets the zero point in the center
        };
});
```

The takeway from this should be the logic and not the code itself. I haven't tried it and am pretty sure there may be errors still.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
the div has a large backgroundimage , larger than its width and height

// HTML

```
<div id="pageBg">
</div>
```

//CSS

```
#pageBg {
    background: url(images/pageBg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 768px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;   
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

// Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pageBg').mousemove(function(e){
      var mousePosY = (e.pageY/$(window).width())*100;
      $('#pageBg').css('background-position-y', mousePosY +'%');
   }); 
});
```